# Action Bar icons disappear when the drawer is opened

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, android-menu

I'm new to Android. I'm trying to add 2 icons in my action bar. So, I used `getSupportActionBar().setIcon()` to do this. Here is the code I used `onCreate()`.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)

    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment
       .setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"))); // change the color of header

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name){

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();          }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_deals);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_loc);
    }
```

When I oen the drawer icons disappear from the Action bar. Bu, when I re-open it icons appear again.

Anyone have an idea what is happening here?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: you should use a menu

Comment: Like @MalekHijazi said, please refer to this link for more information on menu resource. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: Yeah! tried it too. It's working. But, when I expanding the navigation drawer icon dissapears. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove invalidateOptionsMenu() from onDrawerClosed() and onDrawerOpened() and see whether the icons disappear when the drawer is opened.

As you didn't post the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method, I guess thats where the problem lies. invalidateOptionsMenu() calls the onPrepareOptionsMenu() and I guess thats where the code is present to hide the icons when the drawer is opened.

P.S: posting as separate answer, as I couldn't comment.

Answer (score 2):

You Can try Following this [Link](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-simple-menu-example.html).

Check this out and tell me if it worked or not.

Or you can do some thing like this.
Create menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/next"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_next"
          android:title="@string/next" />
  <item android:id="@+id/previous"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_previous"
        android:title="@string/previous" />
  <item android:id="@+id/list"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
        android:title="@string/list" /> 
</menu>
```

And now you will be able to set ICON on menu

Now in CreateOptionMenu

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
  return true;
}
```

And to access that menu.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case R.id.next:
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the " + getResources().getString(R.string.next) + " menu option",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
  …
  default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah! tried it too. It's working. But, when I expanding the navigation drawer icon dissapears. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you remove getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_deals) and 
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_loc);

Comment: Yes I did. When expanding the navigation drawer icons dissapear and when close the navigation drawer icon apeear. This continues. What should I do?

Comment: Remove getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle) and getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title) from onDrawerOpened and onDrawerClosed and add super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView) in onDrawerOpened and super.onDrawerClosed(view) in onDrawerClosed.  


getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title) can be called from onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: Why is it still hapenning? edited the post. Can you please just look at it and give me a solution?

Comment: User toolbar (http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html). Set toolbar as actionbar by setSupportActionBar() and then later make any use of getSupportActionBar()

Change your app theme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar. This will remove the default action bar and your toolbar can then be used as action bar. Remaining functionality of adding menu icon stays same.

Comment: Sorry I cannot understand what you are telling. :( I didn't use a toolbar  here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108378/discussion-between-devanshu-dwivedi-and-quality-products).

Comment: Follow up with this project. https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/poliveira/apps/materialtests

You can have a better understanding of what I am trying to say.

Comment: The project conveys my intent completely and thats the solution I am trying to convey. Check styles.xml, toolbar_default.xml to see how navigation drawer works.

Comment: but, this project doesn't have icons in action bar. :(

Comment: Once you do setSupportActionBar on toolbar, rest of the code stays same. Icons come.